# Excluding email option from QLPreviewController in iOS6+

Tags: ios, ios6, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I was wondering if you can remove the `mail` option from the share menu in a `QLPreviewController`? I have searched up and down the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/QLPreviewController/delegate) but couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is remove the share button completely via viewDidAppear:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
```

Then you can create your own button that handles its on UIActivityViewController items with different activities that exclude mail.

See something like this for more info on creating that: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-beyers/cocoaconf-dc-recap-sharing-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: I've had it work just fine in 6 and 7. Your controller HAS to be in a navigationcontroller, however

Comment: are you sure? afaik, in iOS7 it is now a remote view controller called via XPC

Comment: Yes I'm sure. You just have to do it in viewDidAppear (after all of their work has been done). It's a stacking thing....so if you try to do it earlier, it will not work.

Comment: I also managed to achieve this on iOS 7.1. It won't work if you don't call [super viewDidAppear] first.